# How to interact with a component inside a User Control in the Designer

Tags: wpf, user-controls, designer

I would allow the push of a button located in a User Control from the designer to change the current TabItem of a TabControl.

How can I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Show some code (xaml). Is the tab control outside the user control?

Comment: Are you talking about Visual Studio's Designer ?

Comment: Yes it's the Visual Studio's Designer. The button and the TabControl are in the same UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` property eather by binding or by code behind.

EDIT:
If you added your user control in the other window, you cannot access the controls on the user control. You have to open the user conrol .xaml and edit it there. You can make public method that will route out the button click. I think that is what you need.

Comment: The problem is that I can't click on the button from the designer to set SelectedIndex or SelectedItem.

Comment: @CurtisWheller What kind of designer are you using?

Comment: It's the designer of Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I think it's possible. For example when you add a standard TabControl to a Window, you can select a TabItem and modify its heading even if it is a inner component of the TabControl.